# Order to deploy Aspnet site + Services

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-6, webdeploy, application-pool

I have an aspnet website ans some services and Id like to know the best pratice and security order to made a deploy and avoid problems after this.
Id like to know if there is best pratice order and/or the best way to do this.

I have some doubts about the order to do like: stop website, stop all pools (y/n?), start the website before pools, recycle pools always (s/n) and others doubts correlated.

I have 3 scenarios:

1. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZojAp.png) - Update the website and install a new wcf service
2. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwKYb.png) - Update
   the website and update a wcf service
3. [3] - Only Update the website
4. [4] - Only Update a service

How can I proceed following each scenarios?

Some pics to ilustrate:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This can really be answered by you taking the time to think through what depends on what and experiment.

Comment: Hello @mason ! My question is a little more about how and best practices to make a deploy in each situations discribed here.

Comment: "Best practices" is an opinion. And not on topic for Stack Overflow. Just experiment and find what works best for you.